# nginx - location {} access_log off -> no such file or directory

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to improve the reverse proxy's virtual hosts' configuration files of my company,

but I'm facing an issue that I can't understand:

In the "location / " block I inserted these lines

```
location ~* ^.+\.(eot|otf|woff|woff2|ttf|rss|atom|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
        }
```

and everythings fine,

```
==> /var/log/nginx/example.access.log <==

172.18.0.1 - - [26/Feb/2024:08:36:44 +0000] "GET /wp-content/themes/example/images/back-numbers.png HTTP/1.1" 200 264666 "https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/example/css/style.css?ver=5.6.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

it doesn't log the gets to these extentions and so on but when I put the following line,

```
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    expires 1y;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

the site changes aspect and logs are filles with "no such file or directory"

```
==> /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log <==
2024/02/26 08:34:46 [error] 107#107: *336 open() "/etc/nginx/html/wp-content/themes/example/webfonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /wp-content/themes/example/webfonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/example/css/style.css?ver=5.6.1"
```

It looks like it changes, some way, the root directory, but being reverse proxies I didn't set it up.

here below you can fine the virtual host conf file.

thanks in advance for every suggestion

Rob

```
##################
## plain http
##################

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name exampl.com;
    return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

## cyphered https
##################
##################

server {
    # SRV NAME
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;

    # TLS
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/websites/www.example.com/www.example.com.crt;
      # --> ricordati di appendere il bundle nel crt <--
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/websites/www.example.com/www.example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
}

server {
    # SRV NAME
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

    # TLS
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/websites/www.example.com/www.example.com.crt;
      # --> ricordati di appendere il bundle nel crt <--
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/websites/www.example.com/www.example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

    # OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    
    # Security Headers
    fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;                 
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;        
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";      
    add_header Set-Cookie "Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure"; 
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache';    
    # config to enable HSTS(HTTP Strict Transport Security)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' *.youtube.com maps.gstatic.com *.googleapis.com *.google-analytics.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com assets.zendesk.com connect.facebook.net; frame-src 'self' *.youtube.com assets.zendesk.com *.facebook.com s-static.ak.facebook.com tautt.zendesk.com; object-src 'self'; default-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; form-action 'self'";

    # header and cache expiration
    expires epoch;                                    

    # security
    #Autenticazioneauth_basic           "Authentication required";
    #Autenticazioneauth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;



location / {
                                        
    proxy_pass                          https://example.portals:97/ ; # in caso di redirect su URI !=
                                                            # si disabilita il proxy_ssl_verify
    # include proxy_params;
    proxy_set_header Host               $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout                  900;
    proxy_headers_hash_max_size         512;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size      128;
    proxy_ssl_verify                    off; # disabilitato perchè non in possesso della CA.pem
    proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate       /etc/ssl/websites/example.com/example.com.ca-bundle;
    proxy_ssl_verify_depth              2;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse             on;
    proxy_ssl_name                      $proxy_host;

##########################
#
#   THESE BLOCKS WORK FINE
#
##########################

    # Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
    location ~* ^.+\.(eot|otf|woff|woff2|ttf|rss|atom|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
        }
    location ~* \.(?:cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        client_max_body_size 0;
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
        }

##########################
#
#   THESE BLOCKS BREAK ALL
#
##########################

    # # Media: images, icons, video, audio send expires headers
    # location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm)$ {
    #     expires 1M;
    #     access_log off;
    #     add_header Cache-Control "public";
    #     }
    # Web fonts send expires headers
    # location ~* \.(?:eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
    #     expires 3M;
    #     access_log off;
    #     add_header Cache-Control "public";
    #     }
    # # HTML send expires headers.
    # location ~* \.(html)$ {
    #     expires 7d;
    #     access_log off;
    #     add_header Cache-Control "public";
    #     }
    #  Browser caching of static assets.
    #  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)$ {
    #      expires 7d;
    #      add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
    #      }
    #  CSS and Javascript send expires headers.
    #  location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    #    expires 1y;
    #    access_log off;
    #    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    #  }
}

# Enable Gzip compression in NGNIX.
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_static on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 512;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;

gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml text/javascript image/svg+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf text/x-component font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject;


location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    # include the fastcgi_param setting
    include fastcgi_params;
    # SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter is used for PHP FPM determining
    #  the script name. If it is not set in fastcgi_params file,
    # i.e. /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params or in the parent contexts,
    # please comment off following line:
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    location ~ \wp-login.php$ {
        allow 192.168.0.0/16;
        deny all;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/appname.sock;
        }
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    #fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/appname.sock;

}

location = /robots.txt {
   add_header Content-Type text/plain;
   return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [nginX location match tester](https://nginx.viraptor.info/), no location in your config file matches the TTF file requested with http://example.com/webfonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf

[image]

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,
then the points become:

1- where should I put these directives so that they become effective
2- why when I put them both in the "server block"  and in the "location /" block they block the extentions instead of stop logging them ?
thanks

Comment: If you have more than one `location` directive which uses regex - the first match will win. My advice is to (temporarily) simplify the config file and leave only the bare minimum - location blocks and `access_log` directives. Will be simpler for debugging.